# Why doesn't my table view work?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a view that has a table view inside. I've got a viewController class that has a table view declared and everything is hooked up in the interface builder.

But methods don't work, such as:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 61;
}
```

Under viewDidLoad, I am able alter tableView cell height by doing this

```
self.tableView.rowHeight=71;
```

I'm confused as to what's going on.....

Some more information:
I'm using Xcode 4.3
iOS 5
And I'm using storyboards...here's what my view looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the delegate and dataSource outlets are pointing back at the same tableview, if I understand your screenshot properly. These outlets should connect to your view controller, and then you must be sure that your view controller is not being released by mistake (I don't suspect that it is based on what you have shared, but it's good to keep in mind).

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I was supposed to connect both dataSource and delegate to File's Owner.

Comment: view controller** not file's owner